# Where is whitespace visibility toggled in VisualStudio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, whitespace

I am looking for a setting in Visual Studio 2010 (It was in 08 I'm sure it's in 10)

Basically it makes it easy to see the indentation/spacing of code because in the white space it buts spaced fullstops (which are obviously a different color) and it makes it really easy to see the indentation of your code.

But I can't find the setting now i'm trying to reconfigure my settings in VS 2010.

Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit | Advanced | View white space  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>)

If you're using the Express version of Visual Studio, it's possible that you need to enable "Expert Mode" to see the menu option (or it might not be there at all for all I know - I don't have Express installed to check).

Answer (score 1):

A related setting is in Tools / Options / Text Editor / All Languages / Tabs.  If everyone agrees on a common setting, it simplies readability between users.

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcut, probally easier to remember:

```
CTRL-SHIFT-8
```

FYI to find a specific shortcut in general, look into:

```
Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
```

Where you can search for stuff too.

(Sepecific to VS 2010)