# Hide the space-indicator in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio there is a negative sign ("-") that indicates white space. What can I do to hide it?

URL my image:

http://s4.picofile.com/file/7844095692/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: Common question, just easier to answer it then finding the dup.  Edit + Advanced + View white space.  Click around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: Also `Ctrl+r, Ctrl+w` changes `View white space`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find whitespace display setting in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401637/cant-find-whitespace-display-setting-in-vs-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit\Advanced\View White Space