# How to remove dotted line from text editor in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, settings, text-editor

Unfortunately I hit some shortcut from Visual Studio text editor.After that there will be a dotted line in my text editor along with every code.i tried by resetting Environment from tool menu.

Still also am getting those line.

It makes my editor seems bad.

So please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Edit + Advanced, View White Space.  Looks like a "dotted line" when turned on.

Comment: @HansPassant, your suggestion works. You should take your comments to a response and the original author of the post should mark your response as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide the signs space the visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629870/hide-the-signs-space-the-visual-studio)

Answer (score 44):

I am assuming, You must have hit CTRL+E & CTRL+S by mistake.
You can get rid of those dotted lines by pressing the same keys again or go to EDIT tab -> Advanced and click on "View White Space"

I guess this should eradicate the problem

Comment: This fixed it for me, old question but this answer is correct.

Comment: Works on VS2019 (FYI, I use with C# 2005 key bindings)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the vertical lines connecting indented blocks of text, the answer is `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `General` -> `Show structure guide lines`

Answer (score 1):

Click **View** then down below you'll find **Render Whitespace** click on that and it will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+shift+p to open the command palette and search for *toggle render whitespaces* and click it and the dotted white spaces will disappear.